# Which is better Dragon Armor or Turtle armor

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

My friend and I Both have turtle armor and I want to know which is better dragon armor or turtle armor. This is relating to defense and over all stats for a melee play through . May somebody inform me if which one is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's compare the two, shall we?

**[Dragon Armor](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Armor)**

Defense - 60
Set Bonus:

- 21% Melee and movement speed

**[Turtle Armor](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Turtle_Armor)**

Defense - 65
Set Bonus:

- 14% increased melee damage
- 12% increase melee critical strike chance
- Reflects 100% damage taken by melee attacks.
- Enemies are more likely to target you.

I would be more inclined to go with the Turtle Armor. Reflecting melee damage back to an attacker is **very** useful for Hard Mode. With the increased critical strike chance, this armor set actually gives you an effective 27% melee damage increase over the Dragon Armor's 21%. This comes from the fact that a critical hit doubles the damage, so a 12% chance for what amounts to an "extra" hit stacks multiplicative on top of the original increased melee damage.

The only thing you lose out on is the movement speed, which really isn't a priority of mine when playing Hard Mode. When you get wings, movement speed will likely be the most unimportant stat since your freedom of movement will be great enough as it is.

Comment: Yeah I already defeated plantera and I have all the other hard mode stuff. So I'm pretty far in